Where was it first established that Clayface was weak to electricity?
In Creature Commandos Season 1 Episode 5 "The Iron Pot," Eric Frankenstein fights Clayface and struggles until they both get electrocuted by live wires.
During their fight, Clayface had the upper hand by engulfing Frankenstein within his malleable clay form. However, Frankenstein turned the tables by grabbing electrical wiring and using it against both of them. While Frankenstein was seemingly immune to electricity, Clayface was destroyed by the shock. At first, I thought this wouldn't work (as per Pokémon rules—Electric-type moves have no effect on Ground-types), but clearly DC Comics has different rules.

Anyway, the scene made me wonder: In which DC media was it first established that Clayface is weak to electricity?

The earliest instance I'm aware of is "Holiday Knights" (September 13, 1997), S01E01 of The New Batman Adventures, in which the DCAU version of Clayface, Matt Hagen, is electrocuted and rendered unconscious by power lines.




The New Batman Adventures - S01E01 - "Holiday Knights"

He initially appeared to die by electrocution in "Feat of Clay: Part II" (September 9, 1992), S01E05 of Batman: The Animated Series, but it was subsequently revealed that he faked his death and that electricity (at that time) had "no effect" on him.




Batman: The Animated Series - S01E05 - "Feat of Clay: Part II"

I've been looking through prior comicbook issues, but can't seem to find an earlier instance.
